# Is there any method of determining the exact nature(purely real or imaginary) of all the roots of a cubic polynomial??

Tags: linear-algebra

Actually I would like to request to please share  all the methods of determining the nature of all the roots of a cubic polynomial WITHOUT finding the roots. I have devised a method just want to ensure if my method is unique and also please suggest the best place to get my paper published. Please guide me regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cubic-discriminant/) is likely the most common method.

Answer (score 2):

[The Wikipedia article on “discriminant”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) says:

> The cubic polynomial $ ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$ has discriminant $$ b^{2}c^{2}-4ac^{3}-4b^{3}d-27a^{2}d^{2}+18abcd.$$
>   In particular, the polynomial $x^{3}+px+q$ has discriminant
>   $$ -4p^{3}-27q^{2}.$$
>   The discriminant is zero if and only if at least two roots are equal. If the coefficients are real numbers, and the discriminant is not zero, the discriminant is positive if the roots are three distinct real numbers, and negative if there is one real root and two complex conjugate roots.

Note that if two roots are equal, all roots are real. So the classification is very similar to that of the quadratic: if the discriminant is positive, the roots are real and distinct; if zero the roots are real but not all distinct,; and if negative the roots are distinct but two are complex conjugate.